# JQuery doesn't work from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

Guys i have a big problem, I have this jquery (I think) code, this code doesn't works from the ajax, and I don't know why, maybe someone can help me.

```
function showname(id){
    $.ajax({
       url:'tooltip.php',
       data:{id:id},
       async: false,
       success:function(response)
       {
          // use response for tooltip
          alert(response);
       }
    });
});
}
```

I put an alert on the php code, and the php code works when I call from url (like http://mysite.com/tooltip.php?id=LNFC without " ' ") that code must return the result of the query done on php code.

Php code

```
<?php 
$q="SELECT complete_name from mytable where id='".$_REQUEST['id']."'" or die(mysql_error()); 
$result=mysql_query($q,$conection); 
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
echo $row['complete_name']; 
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: add an error method, guessing it is not successful.

Comment: `async: false;` why????

Comment: async: false, is cruel it will kill

Comment: You can only make AJAX calls to/from the same domain... are you trying to get something from a different site?  Also --> don't forget to include this: `type: 'post'` in your ajax call.

Comment: async is deprecated now in latest version of jquery

Comment: _"this code doesn't works from the ajax"_ - What do you mean by that? What actually happens when the code runs? Do you get an error on the PHP side, or...?

Comment: Why the extra `);` in the end?

Comment: are you sure you're calling function `showname()`?

Comment: async:false It's the only way than I have to show the answer into alert javascript way.

I don't have idea of what do you need, or what I should to add, please do you can tell me what do you wish to I must to add?, thanks.

And the ajax doesn't call to php code that part it's the only sure, but I don't know why.

If I put an alert(id); under "function showname(id){" line, that show me LNFC on alert, but if i put the same alert under the last }); doesn't work.

Comment: Drixon Oseña

I'm shure than I'm call showname(); because if I put just this in the function, it works.


function desplegar(id){
alert(id);
}

Comment: i guess you mean `function showname(id){id}` and not `function showname(){});`?

Comment: All php code it's right, the code show me all info than I need, but!!! seems the ajax code doesn't call to the php code.

Comment: Manish I have the end but when I copy the code, I don't copied the last part (the end).

Comment: Dixon Oseña I tryed your solution but, doesn't work.

Comment: Drixson Oseña you was right it's 

I'm call showname(); because if I put just this in the function, it works. function showname(id){ alert(id); }

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
function showname(id){
    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:'tooltip.php',
       data:{id:id},
       success:function(response) {
          // use response for tooltip
          alert(response);
       },
       error:function(response) {
           alert(response.errorThrown); 
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: So, no alerts in the response? what about the developer console on your browser? Does it show any error?

Comment: Just said me 

Uncaught ReferenceError $ is not defined  under the $ajax({

Comment: Remember to add this line at the top of your webpage: 

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: Leonardo, I found your answer searching the error in google, but, you're right that was the problem.